# bar when save BasicDBObject

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I am trying to save an object with lists however, when I save it the document appears with "\", like that:

> \"tags\":[\"java\",\"eclipse\",\"jdbc\",\"jpa\",\"hibernate\",\"jee\",\"jsp\",\"servlets\",\"taglibs\",\"tagfiles\",\"mvc\",\"ajax\",\"spring\",\"tomcat\"]

When I print my map instance with `toString()` the result is without those "\", however, 
when I print my BasicDBObject it returns me the result with "\"

```
public void save(Map<String, Object> mapInstance) {

    BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject(mapInstance);

    collection.insert(document);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't directly accepts *strings of JSON*. You need to parse those into `BasicDBObject`s first. You can do that with something like:

```
Object o = com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(mapInstance);
DBObject dbObj = (DBObject) o;

collection.insert(dbObj);
```

Comment: Tanks @Derick, that help me a lot